# Django: select_related() / prefetch_related() among 4 tables

Tags: python, sql, django, django-select-related

I would like to query across 4 tables ( directions, layers, metal stack, and layers). I have the majority of the query done except for one part which I will explain further below. I need a resulting table with the columns layers, directions, stackname, width.

In sql, it would be something like:

```
Class stack():
    id
    stackname

Class layers():
    id
    layers

Class directions():
    id
    directions

Class List():
    directions_id= models.ForeignKey(directions)
    layers_id= models.ForeignKey(layers)
    metalstack_id= models.ForeignKey(stack)
    width


SELECT layers, directions, stackname, width
FROM List 
JOIN layers l
ON l.id = List.layers_id
JOIN directions d
ON d.id = List.directions_id
JOIN stack s
ON s.id = List.metalstack_id;
```

The query below gets me layers_id, directions_id, stack_id, width which values are correct. However instead of getting the id, I want to have the layers, directions and stackname value instead. I tried changing it to
`values("stackname","directions", "layers","pitch","space","width")` but it did not work.

**views.py**

```
list= List.objects
.filter(metalstack_id__in=stackid)
.select_related('directions','layers','stackname')
.values("metalstack_id","directions_id",layers_id","width")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Django's `first()`, `last()` queryset methods according to your needs.

```py
SomeModel.objects.filter(field_name=value).values("id", "name").first()
```

Full documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#first

Comment: Do you know something that allows more flexibility in querying across different tables? As you have seen, my models.py has alot of relationships between them. Possibility across 3 tables?

Comment: you might want to look into `select_related` and `prefetch_related`